# Keeping the same scale but a different range of horizontal axes of two plots in a grid

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

We have two plots.

```
g1 = Plot[{1 - 2 x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}];
g2 = Plot[ 1 - 2 x,         {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}];
Grid[{
  {g1, g2}
  }]
```

This gives something like:
[image]

What I need is something like the following (same scale but different range of horisontal axes):
[image]

It is important to keep the same plot Range. And it would be nice to have it automatically, not playing manually with inches. `Grid` is not obligatory if there is more convenient way.

That sort of graphics often arises in economics when so called 'horizontal summation' takes place, i.e. demand function in essence is of the form `x[y]` in normal terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> {Automatic, height}` for both plots:

```
opts = {PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}};
g1 = Plot[{1 - 2 x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 2}, Evaluate@opts];
g2 = Plot[1 - 2 x, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@opts];
Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]

Then one can play around with ticks.

Comment: Oh, `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.  How did I miss that.

Comment: @Edmund It simple to miss because here the default value is not `Automatic`.

Answer (score 4):

The `AspectRatio` is determining the size of the axis in the plots. These can be set for each plot along with the `ImageSize` for the results you are seeking. Also, the `PlotRange` needs to set the x-axis separate from the y-axis for the second plot.

`AspectRatio` is a $\frac{\text{height}}{\text{width}}$ ratio so for the first plot we need $\frac{2}{2}$ and for the second we need $\frac{2}{1}$. For `ImageSize` we only need to match the heights since the `AspectRatio` will take care of the widths. Finally, the `PlotRange` of the second plot is set so that it matches the `AspectRatio` to the scale desired.  Here the scale is 1:1 for these.

```
g1 = Plot[{1 - 2 x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}];
g2 = Plot[1 - 2 x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}];
Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]

The ticks on the second plot are a bit bunched but can be set with `Ticks` if needed.

```
xticks = If[Mod[#, .5] == 0, {#, ToString@#, .04}, {#, ""}] & /@ 
  Range[0, 2, 0.1]

g1 = Plot[{1 - 2 x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2},
   Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic},
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}];
g2 = Plot[1 - 2 x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2,
   Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}];
Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]

You can also use `GraphicsGrid` instead of `Grid`.

Comment: why are 'main' ticks on the right plot shorter than on the left?

Comment: it seems like AspectRatio influences ticks marks size...

Comment: @garej Tick mark size is uses `Scaled` by default and this is a function of the width of the graphic. I was trying to get the labeled ticks higher than the unlabeled ones. You don't have to specify tick size.

Answer (score 1):

Overlay second plot with white Rectangle

```
g1 =
 Plot[
  {1 - 2 x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 2},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Above],
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}];

g2 =
 Plot[1 - 2 x, {x, 0, 2},
  Epilog -> {White, Rectangle[{1., -0.1}, {2, 2.1}]},
  GridLines -> {{0.5, 1}, Automatic},
  ImageSize -> 400,
  PlotRange -> {0, 2},
  Ticks -> {Transpose[{#, PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}] & /@ #}] &[{0., 0.5, 1.}], Automatic}];

Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]